# Retain the values only in those rows of the column based on the condition on other columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a dataframe df_in, which contains column names that start with **pi** and **pm**.

```
df_in = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,"",6,7,8,9],["",1,32,43,59,65,"",83,97],["",51,62,47,58,64,74,86,99],[73,51,42,67,54,65,"",85,92]], columns=["piabc","pmed","pmrde","pmret","pirtc","pmere","piuyt","pmfgf","pmthg"])
```

If a row in column name which starts with **pi** is blank, make the same rows of columns which starts with **pm** also blank till we have a new column which starts with **pi**. And repeat the same process for other columns also.

Expected Output:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,"","",7,8,9],["","","","",59,65,"","",""],["","","","",58,64,74,86,99],[73,51,42,67,54,65,"","",""]], columns=["piabc","pmed","pmrde","pmret","pirtc","pmere","piuyt","pmfgf","pmthg"])
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create groups by compare columns names by [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with cumulative sum and then compare values by empty spaces in `groupby` for mask used for set empty spaces in [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
g = df_in.columns.str.startswith('pi').cumsum()
df = df_in.mask(df_in.eq('').groupby(g, axis=1).transform(lambda x: x.iat[0]), '')

#first for me failed in pandas 1.2.3
#df = df_in.mask(df_in.eq('').groupby(g, axis=1).transform('first'), '')


print (df)
  piabc pmed pmrde pmret pirtc pmere piuyt pmfgf pmthg
0     1    2     3     4                 7     8     9
1                           59    65                  
2                           58    64    74    86    99
3    73   51    42    67    54    65
```